# How do I access Glassfish V3 Administration Console Website from a remote host

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, application-server, glassfish-3

I have installed Glassfish v3 on a standalone server running ubuntu-server 9.10.

I can open the Admin website if I use a browser running on the server by browsing to:
http:// localhost:4848/

I would like to access it from a remote machine by browsing to something like
http:// mydomain.com:4848/

The firewall is definitely allowing traffic through on that port (4848) and I can access the application server by browsing to:
http:// mydomain.com:8080/

How can I allow remote access to the administration website?

Comment: what do you see when you attempt to access http://mydomain.com:4848 from a remote machine?

Is there something in the domain's log file that indicates that something is amiss?

Answer (score 2):

It is 'allowed' by default, so there may be some you may need to ask a different question...

Comment: It turns out that the firewall was the issue - lesson learned: don't take anyone elses word for something, check it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853266/is-glassfish-admin-console-port-4848-secure/854440#854440) mentions the configuration of listeners for the admin console. Although it focusses on SSL, this configuration area may be the place where you can enable/disable access to the admin console from other other host.