# GlassFish Application Server Does Not Prompt for User Name and Password when Accessing Admin Console

Tags: glassfish, cluster-computing

I have an issue with Glassfish 2.1.1 after I enable cluster, that I lost login page ! and after I type `http://localhost:4848` link,  directly I be in Administration Console without ask me anything about authentication info (username/password)!

I installed it and select to Promote me username/password, and it was shown to me and redirected to `http://localhost:4848/login.jsf`, and now that login page doesn't shown to me anymore, but this happened after I enable cluster, I putting this question here after long search to how get login page back again and without luck.

My `asadminenv.conf` file:

```
AS_ADMIN_PORT=4848
AS_ADMIN_PROFILE=cluster
AS_ADMIN_SECURE=true
```

From `domain.xml` file (JVM Options) :

```
<jvm-options>-Djava.security.auth.login.config=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/login.conf</jvm-options>
```

`login.conf` content:

```
/*  Copyright 2004 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All rights reserved.    */
/*  SUN PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms. */

fileRealm {
    com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.FileLoginModule required;
};

ldapRealm {
    com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LDAPLoginModule required;
};

solarisRealm {
    com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.SolarisLoginModule required;
};

jdbcRealm {
    com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.JDBCLoginModule required;
};
jdbcDigestRealm {
       com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.JDBCDigestLoginModule required;
};
assertedRealm{
    com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.AssertedLoginModule required;
};
```

I hope I can find answer here.

I don't know what details you want, but you can ask me that in comments.

**Edit:** I found exception, I dont know if that related to my issue :

```
[#|2012-06-14T10:09:41.361+0300|WARNING|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-4848-0;_RequestID=7f709123-18b5-4c5a-a0c0-78e5ad2a800b;|jmaki.runtime.jsf.AjaxWrapperPhaseListener.afterPhase(AjaxWrapperPhaseListener.java:69)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:175)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:114)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:102)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
com.sun.faces.extensions.avatar.lifecycle.PartialTraversalLifecycle.execute(PartialTraversalLifecycle.java:80)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
com.sun.enterprise.tools.admingui.servlet.DelayedInitFacesServlet.service(DelayedInitFacesServlet.java:89)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:333)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:240)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:313)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:666)
com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:597)
com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:872)
com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLReadTask.process(SSLReadTask.java:444)
com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLReadTask.doTask(SSLReadTask.java:230)
com.sun.enterprise.web.portunif.PortUnificationPipeline$PUTask.doTask(PortUnificationPipeline.java:382)
com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:264)
com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106)
|#]

[#|2012-06-14T10:09:41.366+0300|SEVERE|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-4848-0;_RequestID=7f709123-18b5-4c5a-a0c0-78e5ad2a800b;|StandardWrapperValve[FacesServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.ViewRootUtil.getLayoutDefinitionKey(ViewRootUtil.java:271)
 at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.restoreView(LayoutViewHandler.java:611)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:179)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:102)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
 at com.sun.faces.extensions.avatar.lifecycle.PartialTraversalLifecycle.execute(PartialTraversalLifecycle.java:80)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
 at com.sun.enterprise.tools.admingui.servlet.DelayedInitFacesServlet.service(DelayedInitFacesServlet.java:89)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:333)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
 at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:240)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:313)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
 at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:666)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:597)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:872)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLReadTask.process(SSLReadTask.java:444)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLReadTask.doTask(SSLReadTask.java:230)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.portunif.PortUnificationPipeline$PUTask.doTask(PortUnificationPipeline.java:382)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:264)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106)
|#]

[#|2012-06-14T10:
```

**Update:**
I just change title, like a link I found : http://www.wikiconsole.com/wiki/?p=2878 but that not helped me too, because I was limited in server I didn't restart server (OS) after I removed :

```
grant {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

But I restarted Application Server itself, Is that why my changes didn't change anything?

Comment: Have you tried using https instead of http?

Comment: @Preston yes, and same issue, I enabled HHTPS and Secure admin and login not enabled !

Comment: How do you know it's actually up and running? What does the server.log show?

Comment: HTTPS up ! I changed it from Admin Console and after restart its redirect me to https if I use http, I followed : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853266/is-glassfish-admin-console-port-4848-secure & about server log, no strange exceptions from glassfish side.

Comment: Does the log confirm that the server is up and running?

Comment: @Preston sorry for late, I don't see confirmation on log, except something like `Loading application * done in 149,788 ms` ! But in console yes, I got message `Command start-domain executed successfully.` ! and I can go to Admin Console, I just have an issue with admin didn't asks me about login info, even I click logout still in Admin Console and I can do anything I want.

Comment: Please use the correct tag which is `cluster-computing`, please don't roll this back. Thanks.

Comment: If you are on UNIX/linux, please let us know what the output of the following command is: which asadmin.  It may be useful to put the content of the server log file up on paste bin so folks can examine it a bit more closely.  What is the value of $PATH, too?

Comment: @vkraemer I can't now, in production now and one, I cant do restarting for that !

Comment: @vkraemer I finally found an exception, can you see this, and sorry for that too late :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed so limited to Solaris OS, the issue is about :

```
grant {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

In security policy file of JDK or JRE `lib/security/java.policy` , this seems the issue, so just avoid using this at all.

Helpful link: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/ENV03-J.+Do+not+grant+dangerous+combinations+of+permissions

Anyway I just upgraded my glassfish and JDK and seems everything back to normal behavior, without adding AllPermissions, everything is OK, the issue was not because the cluster mainly btu the security policy.